# How to Store Data in a List - R

Tags: r

I hope someone can be of help here.

I'm using R and I've reached a situation where I need to store returned data from a function, the data is in the form a vector. So for example, the function may return:

```
c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

Suppose I have a list I have already created before:

```
#I have to store 10 values
alpha = list(rep(NA, 10))
```

How can I store the returned vector in my list? For example, something along the lines of:

```
alpha[1] = c(1,2,3,4,5)
```

So then:

```
alpha = (c(1,2,3,4,5), NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can use `as.list(rep(NA, 10))`

Comment: Use double `[[` - so `alpha[[1]] = c(1,2,3,4,5)` will do it.

Comment: Super, thanks both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you may have some learning to do about lists.  They are a powerful feature in R ([more reading](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html))  The `apply` family (`lapply` and `mapply`, etc.) can often help you avoid this sort of behavior in general.  But to answer your question:

```
alpha <- as.list(rep(NA, 10))

alpha[[1]] <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

print(alpha)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] NA
```

A simple example of using `lapply`:

```
myfunc <- function(input) {
  return(input + 10)
}

lapply(1:10, myfunc)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 11
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 12
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 13
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 14
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 15
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 16
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 17
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 18
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 19
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 20
```

Also, it is helpful to know that the `[` operator returns a list while the `[[` operator returns the element of a list.  (And the same applies for replacement)

To answer your follow-up question: `list` tries to define a list (i.e. something like `list(obj,obj2,obj3)`), whereas `as.list` tries to convert an object to a list.  Since `rep()` creates a vector, `list(rep())` gives you a list of length one (with the output of `rep()` inside the first element).  When you want the vector presented as a list, `as.list` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you, that works well, may I ask what is the difference between list and as.list?

Comment: See updated answer to address `list` versus `as.list`.  [Also see the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.html).  You can get the same help by typing `?list` in the R console.